# Odd Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

I see questions about this error all over the internet and most of them are unique typos or misunderstandings of syntax.

However, this is very odd. Here is my code, the ENTIRE file (intended to be accessed by AJAX):

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("(censored)", "(censored)", "(censored)") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("(censored)_users", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['user'] . "<br />";

}

?>
```

This was copy and pasted from another script on my site to list users; the only modification was modifying the `echo $row['user']` line because it contained a lot more.

This gives the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in (blah blah blah blah).php on line 1
```

The first thing that struck me as odd about that was how it was supposedly on line *1*- there's whitespace and a `<?php` tag.

Then, after some frustration, I commented all that out and before it placed `echo "Hello World!";`

Well, it gave me a similar error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in (blah blah blah blah blah).php on line 1
```

The rest of the PHP on my site is working fine. What could be causing errors on this particular script?

Comment: Have you verified that you're encoding in the same format as your server expects? I seem to remember that happening sometimes if the file had a B.O.M. (byte-order-mark) at the top.

Comment: The line numbers tend to be next to useless for those errors. You haven't got anything in your DB password or username that might need escaping?

Comment: Did you just try to run the file? instead of calling it via AJAX

Comment: @TiesonT. I tried 'Show All Characters' in Notepad++ and the only special ones were carriage returns.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd I have not even started worrying about AJAX yet

Comment: Upload the censored file somewhere? I have a feeling it has to do with the encoding or something.

Comment: @Cheezey, are you sure the (bla bla bla) file is the same you are showing?

Comment: @AlexLunix It could be my new FTP client... I'll try downloading the file and looking at it.

Comment: Make sure you are transferring the php files in ASCII mode.

Comment: I just downloaded the file and there are no newlines of any kind. I'll start looking through the options.

Comment: Just for giggles, try doing a `print_r` or `var_dump` on `$row`, just to make sure you're not trying to access a non-existent key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My new FTP client (WinSCP) seems to be stripping out all the carriage returns. I'm currently messing with the options to see if I can change that.

Comment: @Hamish Can't. It has answers.

Comment: As long as the question is written such that someone else with the exact same problem could find it, it could still be useful. The answer to this question is "make sure your FTP client isn't stripping out all your line breaks."

Comment: If it's an FTP client problem, use FileZilla. I've never had problems with it.